# insert-sort with reduce clojure

Tags: clojure, functional-programming

I have function

```
(defn goneSeq [inseq uptil]
  (loop [counter 0  newSeq [] orginSeq inseq]
    (if (== counter uptil)
      newSeq
      (recur (inc counter) (conj newSeq (first orginSeq)) (rest orginSeq)))))

(defn insert [sorted-seq n]
  (loop [currentSeq sorted-seq counter 0]
    (cond (empty? currentSeq) (concat sorted-seq (vector n))
          (<= n (first currentSeq)) (concat (goneSeq sorted-seq counter) (vector n) currentSeq)
          :else (recur (rest currentSeq) (inc counter)))))
```

that takes in a sorted-sequence and insert the number n at its appropriate position for example: (insert [1 3 4] 2) returns [1 2 3 4].

Now I want to use this function with **reduce** to sort a given sequence so something like:

```
(reduce (insert seq n) givenSeq)
```

What is thr correct way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the function works for inserting a single value, then this would work:

```
(reduce insert [] givenSeq)
```

for example:

```
user> (reduce insert [] [0 1 2 30.5 0.88 2.2])
(0 0.88 1 2 2.2 30.5)
```

Also, it should be noted that `sort` and `sort-by` are built in and are better than most hand-rolled solutions.

Comment: I updated the question and (reduce insert givenSeq) do not work

Comment: fixed-  I had forgotten to provide the seed value (I was unable to test the answer since I did not originally have your code).

Answer (score 1):

May I suggest some simpler ways to do `insert`:

A slowish lazy way is

```
(defn insert [s x]
  (let [[fore aft] (split-with #(> x %) s)]
    (concat fore (cons x aft))))
```

A faster eager way is

```
(defn insert [coll x]
  (loop [fore [], coll coll]
    (if (and (seq coll) (> x (first coll)))
      (recur (conj fore x) (rest coll))
      (concat fore (cons x coll)))))
```

---

By the way, you had better put your `defn`s in bottom-up order, if possible. Use `declare` if there is mutual recursion. You had me thinking your solution did not compile.